# GPS not updating when phone is in sleep mode

Tags: android, gps, sleep, android-alarms

My Application needs to pick up location information at regular intervals. I use `AlarmManager` to do it and it works fine. The problem is that when the phone goes to the standby/sleep mode the GPS location listener gets removed. 
After some time when my `AlarmReceiver` gets fired it looks for the latest location update which it does not get because GPS has been turned off due to the standby mode.

Is there a way how I can wake up the location listener when my `AlarmReceiver` gets fired or any other alternative?

Comment: Hello Umesh, I stuck in same problem. Is their any solution do you have?

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no way around this. Altough, this method can help a little:

```
public void addProximityAlert (double latitude, double longitude, 
                               float radius, long expiration, PendingIntent intent).
```